# Javascript subtotal function only working on first row of table

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am implementing a shopping cart and I have added a `subtotal` field that multiplies item quantity and price and returns the subtotal in the `subtotal` column.

But, my JavaScript function is only calculating the subtotal for the first row and not for all rows.

**Here is the code:**

```
<td style="text-align: left; width: 80px;">PKR<input style="width: 70px;" type="number" id="price1" value="<?php echo $values["item_price"];?>" readonly ></td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 80px;"><br/><input style="width: 60px; " form="myform" type="number"  name="qty[<?php echo $values["item_id"]; ?>]" id="qty" value="<?php echo $values["item_quantity"];?>"></td>
<td style="text-align: left; width: 80px;">PKR<input style="width: 70px; " form="myform" type="number" id="total" value="" readonly></td>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var price1=document.getElementById("price1").value;

  function calculate1() {    
    var quantity1 = document.getElementById("qty").value;
    var x = price1 * quantity1;
    document.getElementById("total").value = x;        
  }
</script>
```

**Note:** I'm calling the `calculate()` function on the `onload` event in `<body>` tag.

Comment: Ypu are giving the id of "price1" in that snippet - if all your rows include that then you will have multiple id's - and so only the first will be used. If you cange the id of each row - you should be able to use that dynamic id in the caluclation.

Comment: can you please guide how i cant uniquely give id for all rows?

Comment: `id-SOME_INDEX_HERE`

Comment: And why not just set value in php?

Comment: how ? can you please edit it?

Comment: You could append the unique id that you are already using elsewhere to the price to create a unique id, ......id="price_<?php echo $values["item_id"]; ?>";.....

Answer (score 0):

If all your fields are `readonly` - then set total value with php and remove your javascript function:

```
<input 
    style="width: 70px; " 
    type="number" 
    value="<?php echo ($values["item_quantity"] * $values["item_price"]) ?>" 
    readonly>
```